# Global click event in ContentPage

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-7.0

I have a page in ContentPage format, displayed through Shell navigation, to show details of an object. I want to implement a system that closes the page and takes me back to the main page when a timer expires. However, this timer needs to reset every time I click anywhere on the page. The entire structure is organized in a grid as the parent, and inside it, there's another grid as the main child. I wanted to implement an event that triggers across the entire page, but upon checking, I only found events for specific regions. Is there a possible solution, or do I have to explicitly include the reset on every individual component within my page?

My application only works on Windows.

I tried using TapGestureRecognizer on both the main grid and the nested one, but the event was only triggered on the parent. It didn't work on the child grid and its components.

Comment: There are no global page level click events even natively

Comment: Is there a library that can solve this problem?

Comment: Not that i know of...

Comment: Instead, an event when clicking inside a grid that also includes its children? A single event, I mean

Comment: @porrokynoa do you have clickable components inside your page? If not, you could add a transparent overlay over your page and add the `TapGestureRecognizer` to it.

Comment: I have buttons and entries

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Is there a possible solution, or do I have to explicitly include the reset on every individual component within my page?

This 'possible solution' is basically an easy way to have a 'reset on every individual component' by iterating the visual tree and attaching events appropriate to the type of the control. I tested it on my MS Surface touch screen and on Android. It handles special cases:

---

###### Button

If you add a Tap recognizer to a button, the button won't work anymore. So we'll add a reset to the other click handlers that may be attached to the button.

---

###### Entry

We  can say that input is detected when the control gets focus, or the text changes perhaps, and this detection won't interfere with the functionality of the control itself.

---

###### Blank Space

Making sure that there is a `Grid` or other content view that covers the entire viewport, attach a tap recognizer to it.

---

[image: demo]

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;
    int _debugCount = 0;
    List<ContentView>_children = new List<ContentView>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (var desc in this.GetVisualTreeDescendants().OfType<View>())
        {
            if (desc is Button button)
            {
                button.Clicked += localOnAnyInput;
            }
            else if (desc is Entry entry)
            {
                entry.TextChanged += localOnAnyInput;
                entry.Focused += localOnAnyInput;
            }
            else
            {
                var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += localOnAnyInput;
                desc.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
            }

            void localOnAnyInput(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                WatchdogTimer.StartOrRestart(
                    initialAction: () => TimerRunning = true,
                    completeAction: () => TimerRunning = false
                );
            }
        }
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        if (count == 1)
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
        else
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
    }
    WatchdogTimer WatchdogTimer { get; } = new WatchdogTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5) };
    public bool TimerRunning
    {
        get => _timerRunning;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_timerRunning, value))
            {
                _timerRunning = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    bool _timerRunning = false;
}
```

---

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GlobalClick.MainPage">

    <Grid
        RowDefinitions="*,200,*,*,*"
        ColumnDefinitions="*,2*,*"
        RowSpacing="20"
        BackgroundColor="Azure">

        <Image
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Source="dotnet_bot.png"
            SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
            HeightRequest="200"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            IsVisible="{Binding TimerRunning}"/>

        <Label
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="Hello, World!"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            FontSize="Medium"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="1"
            x:Name="CounterBtn"
            Text="Click me"
            SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
            Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: The event click in the individual components (Entry, Button) worked. For the grids it worked on me only on that father, on those daughters it does not take perceive the click.